# Windows10 crashes to blue screen after update

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, bsod, crash

I recently bought a HP Spectre Pro 360 off Ebay. The system came with a fresh install of Windows10 & everything was fine until the next day, Windows notified of urgent security updates & proceeded to download & install the updates.

The system crashed to blue screen just as this one:

[image: blue screen on crash]

After auto-reboot, the system loads to this screen asking for diagnostics to be run.

[image]

However, when I run diagnostics, I have only memory or hard disk check options.

[image]

Within, hard disk check, running the 'quick check' or 'extensive check' both bring up the following error:

[image]

I dont understand what is going on. The hard drive is an SSD 256GB. Is it corrupt?

I tried to install Ubuntu, but Ubuntu is unable to find the hard drive as well. I am not sure what to do from here.

Many thanks,

EDIT: AS REQUESTED BY EPOXY, bios settings are:

[image]
[image]

NEXT EDIT: Tried Windows 10 usb to fix the problems, however, none of the options work. As @epoxy said, it appears the hard drive has a problem.

Comment: Are you able to access the BIOS? I believe the key combo is Esc+F10. Once you access, see if it detects the peripherals properly.

Comment: It doesn't appear to show the list of hardward. Im uploading the bios photos above.

Comment: In every way, it seems there is an issue with the storage device. It can be a simple wiring issue or connectivity issue. If you are able to easily access the storage devices at the bottom, you have to try to unplug/plug back if possible. Unless of course it is restricted by any sort of a warranty.

Comment: @Epoxy Yes, it seems like it. None of the medias (Ubuntu or Windows 10 USB) are able to detect an SSD. However, I wonder if the software corrupted the hard drive, shouldn't software be able to fix it too? Is there a chance that the hard drive has gone bad? Thanks

Comment: The software can cause issues and a certain level of logical issues and even more severe issues (i.e. malware etc.) but here it is pointing toward a hardware issue, unfortunately. You are quite welcome! :)

Comment: Software cannot corrupt an SSD or HD such that its very presence is no longer detectable by the machine's firmware. 

Yes, it's entirely possible that the drive has gone bad.

Comment: What I do not understand is Windows 10 was running fine (admittedly I didnt get to test it properly as its a new purchase), so how could the hardware just get up & fail while the update. I guess, unless bad sectors were used to store information & led to subsequent fail. Ive ordered a m2 SSD adapter to see if I can connect it to other device & run partition to see whats going on.